# How do I set these buttons 'id' values to append in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I've been given a code which contains wingding characters that relate to a letter different from its normal attached key, and I'm trying to create a program that deciphers them. Unfortunately I can't work out how to add to the textarea, only overwrite the character already there which isn't very helpful to me.

I'm a complete beginner here, especially to Jscript, so I hope that makes sense.
Can anyone please help?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<!-- PLCKFBGDHMOERJAQNXYIZVXSUT cypher alphabet-->
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="P" style="width:100%"  id="A" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="L" style="width:100%"  id="B" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="C" style="width:100%"  id="C" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="K" style="width:100%"  id="D" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="F" style="width:100%"  id="E" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="B" style="width:100%"  id="F" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="G" style="width:100%"  id="G" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="D" style="width:100%"  id="H" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="H" style="width:100%"  id="I" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="M" style="width:100%"  id="J" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="O" style="width:100%"  id="K" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="E" style="width:100%"  id="L" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="R" style="width:100%"  id="M" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="J" style="width:100%"  id="N" />
<br>
<br>
<!-- I'll add the rest later -->

<textarea id="txtarea" name="txtarea"></textarea>

<script>

// INDIVIDUAL LETTER INPUT CODES
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#A").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('A');
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#B").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('B');
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#C").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('C');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#D").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('D');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#E").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('E');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#F").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('F');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#G").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('G');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#H").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('H');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#I").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('I');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#J").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('J');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#K").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('K');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#L").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('L');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#M").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('M');
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#N").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('N');
});
});
</script>
<!-- Ill add the rest later -->
</body>
```

Comment: `var previous = $('#txtarea').html(); $('#txtarea').html(previous + ' letter');` ??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code considerably using event delegation.  Simply add a `div` around all of your inputs.

```
<div id="letters">
  <input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="P" style="width:100%"  id="A" />
  <input type="submit" style="font-family:'wingdings'" value="L" style="width:100%"  id="B" />
<!-- etc  -->
</div>
```

Then your jQuery would only need one event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var txt=$('#txtarea');
  $("#letters").on('click','input',function() {
    txt.val(txt.val()+this.value);
  });
});
```

I believe that does what you want.

You can create a class that contains the `style` properties and just apply that to all the `input`s as well.

```
.letters {
  font-family:'wingdings';
  width:100%;
}

<input type="submit" class="letters" value="P"/>
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wss9gb6/2/) so you can see it in action.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much! I really do need to get back to reading up on this, totally got ahead of myself there.

Comment: EDIT: Spoke too soon, once I added the rest of the lines it certainly shortened the code, but its no longer making the letter substitutions.

Comment: ..and thanks to you I've worked it out.

The code worked beautifully. If I add the id="" tag at the end of the input line, and change  the jquery to txt.val(txt.val()+this.id); it does exactly what I wanted and cracks the code.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of those unnecessary `document.ready()` functions. One such function is sufficient for all event handlers (it simplifies your code).

You can have simpler code as `.on` method as mentioned above, but, remember `onfocus` and `onblur` are better event handlers for text boxes rather than `click` events.

"try to understand the meaning of those functions before trying them..it will definitely increases ur learning experience ..

For better understanding refer `.val()` and `.append()` methods in [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com). This might help for your problem. I strongly suggest you go for the documentation instead of directly copy and paste the solutions you have got. This is the best thing for a beginner.

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for the link. I'm using this to try and understand more, I just let my ambition get ahead of me.